# How can I run SauceLab's tests with browser flags enabled?

Tags: saucelabs

I have a [Open Souce](https://saucelabs.com/opensauce/) setup to test my code against Firefox and Chrome, now I would like to test it with some flags enabled, e.g. `layout.css.grid.enabled = true` for Firefox, and `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features` for Chrome.

How can I configure Sauce to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
{
  browserName: "chrome",
  // ...
  'goog:chromeOptions': {
    args: ['--enable-experimental-web-platform-features']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this configuration in your custom launchers?

```
    'SL_Chrome': {
        base: 'SauceLabs',
        browserName: 'chrome',
        flags: ['--disable-web-security']
    }
```

flags being whatever you want.